# Flutter - Input TextField gets cleared by TextEditingController but the entered message appears to be 'still alive' (not empty)

Tags: flutter, textfield, texteditingcontroller

I have a chat-app that uses a single **TextField** controlled by a **TextEditingController** to enter text messages.
Pressing the associated **IconButton** sends the message *if the message is not empty* and then clears the TextEditingController. This all works perfectly. After sending the message, the text input field gets cleared.

BUT, here comes the bug, if I press the send button again, the message is sent once more. How come and how can I prevent this?

```
class NewMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMessageState createState() => _NewMessageState();
}

class _NewMessageState extends State<NewMessage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  var _enteredMessage = '';

  void _sendMessage() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').add({
      'text': _enteredMessage,
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      'userId': user.uid,
      'username': userData.data()['username'],
      'userImage': userData.data()['image_url']
    });
    _controller.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              autocorrect: true,
              enableSuggestions: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message...'),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _enteredMessage = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.send,
            ),
            onPressed: _enteredMessage.trim().isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a TextEditingController **AND** an onChanged event for a TextField can be problematic. The issue is discussed in depth here: [TextEditingController vs OnChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904313/texteditingcontroller-vs-onchanged)

In my case, I finally decided to go for an TextEditingController **only** solution. This way, we can get rid of the `_enteredMessage` variable and the *onChanged/setState()* statements alltogether.

Instead, we need to add a listener to our TextEditingController and call `setState()` in our `initState()` method.

Finally, we need to dispose the `_controller` in the `dispose()` method to prevent memory leaks.

Here is the code of my **TextEditingController only solution**:

```
class NewMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMessageState createState() => _NewMessageState();
}

class _NewMessageState extends State<NewMessage> {
  var _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _sendMessage() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').add({
      'text': _controller.text,
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      'userId': user.uid,
      'username': userData.data()['username'],
      'userImage': userData.data()['image_url']
    });
    _controller.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              autocorrect: true,
              enableSuggestions: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message...'),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.send,
            ),
            onPressed: _controller.text.trim().isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the controller in the button callbkack
`_controller.clear()`, but what you are really sending to Firebase is not the `_controller` text but rather the variable
`_enteredMessage` which does not get cleared.

if you just send the controller text instead of `_enteredMessage` the problem should be solved:

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').add({
      'text': _controller.text,
      'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      'userId': user.uid,
      'username': userData.data()['username'],
      'userImage': userData.data()['image_url']
    });
```

Also always dispose your controllers in the Stateful Widget onDispose method to avoid memory leaks.

EDIT:
The condition on which the button callback gets called should also change to:

```
...
onPressed: _controller.text.isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage
...
```

Comment: This simply results in the `onPressed` method sending an empty message to Firebase when the send button is pressed for the second time and thereafter.

Comment: You should change the condition of your onPressed button accordingly: `onPressed: _controller.text.isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage,`

Comment: - croxx5f Of course I have tried that as well. The result is the same. In fact it's exactly the statement you mention that - for some strange reason - does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest solution here is to replace

```
 onPressed: _enteredMessage.trim().isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage,
```

with

```
 onPressed: () {
            if (_controller.text.trim().isNotEmpty) _sendMessage();
          }
```